# Is there a way to web scarpe a website with unchanging URLs?

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape a dynamic page using selenium and beautifulsoup and python and am able to scrape the first page. But when i try to get to the next page, the url doesnt change and when i Inspect, i am unable to see Form Data as well. Can someone can help me?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from parsel import Selector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import re
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd

companies = []
overview = []
people = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\rahul\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://coverager.com/data/companies/')
driver.maximize_window()
src = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('tbody')
descrip = []
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    #print(td)
    row = [i.text.strip() for i in td]
    descrip.append(row)
    #print(row)
    
#file = open('gag.csv','w')
#with file:
#        write = csv.writer(file)
#        write.writerows(descrip)


url = ('https://coverager.com')
a_tags = table.find_all('a', href = True)
for link in a_tags:
       ol = link.get('href')
       pl = link.string.strip()
       #companies.append(row)
       #print(pl)
       #print(ol)
       driver.get(url + ol)
       driver.implicitly_wait(1000)
       data1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tab-details').text
       overview.append(data1.strip())
       data2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('People').click()
       p_tags = driver.find_element_by_class_name('tab-details').text
       people.append(p_tags)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case of https://coverager.com/data/companies/ it would be much easier to scrape the api call instead of the html on the page.

Open dev tools (on chrome right click and hit inspect) and go to the network tab. When you hit the "next" button a row should show up in the network tab. Click on this row and then go to preview. You should see the company in this tab.

The api is accessing links which look like the following:

[https://coverager.com/wp-json/ath/v1/coverager-data/companies?per_page=20&page=2&draw=4&column=3&dir=desc&filters=%7B%22companies%22:[],%22company_lob%22:[],%22industry%22:[],%22company_type%22:[],%22company_category%22:[],%22region%22:[],%22founded%22:[],%22company_stage%22:[],%22company_business_model%22:[]%7D](https://coverager.com/wp-json/ath/v1/coverager-data/companies?per_page=20&page=2&draw=4&column=3&dir=desc&filters=%7B%22companies%22:%5B%5D,%22company_lob%22:%5B%5D,%22industry%22:%5B%5D,%22company_type%22:%5B%5D,%22company_category%22:%5B%5D,%22region%22:%5B%5D,%22founded%22:%5B%5D,%22company_stage%22:%5B%5D,%22company_business_model%22:%5B%5D%7D)

It seems like all the pages call the same api url but change the page= and raw= which are 2 apart.

So, simply use requests to call this class of links and loop through as many pages as you need! You could also change the per_page return as many companies as you need. You will have to test that though.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, that indeed was helpful.

Comment: i also need to scrape the information of each company in that table, like i have done on my code above, but since i can't get any links through this method, i am stuck. Any suggestions on how i could go about it?

Comment: it seems like the best approach to get the company info is to use a more traditional web scraper. I would suggest either requests + beautiful soup or Scrapy. You can collect the urls to get to these company pages from the main website page using either requests + beautiful soup or Scrapy (note: the company urls seem to be https://coverager.com/company/company-name/). To can cycle through the pagination by going to the "next" link after you collect the urls.